# how to access an object (simpleXML) variable name using a string?

Tags: php, object

i need to access a simplexml object using a string. ie.

`$x->a->b = 'obj';`
`$s = 'a->b';`
`echo $x->$s;`

but it doesn't seem to work...

please help!

:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use references:

```
$s =& $x->a->b;
```

or, if you want the string approach, build up the reference step by step:

```
function getRef($base, $str) {
    $out = $base;
    $parts = explode("->", $str);

    foreach ($parts as $p) {
        $out = $out->$p;
    }

    return $out;
}

getRef($x, "a->b");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do that like this, if my memory serves me:

```
echo $x->{$s};
```

Answer (score 0):

That will not work. Are you trying to use xpath?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Comment: hmm i guess i could do.

seems a shame that syntax doesn't work though,

`$x->a = 'obj'; $s = 'a'; echo $x->$s;`

works fine